# How to generate classes using jsonschema2pojo that include a class called "System"?

Tags: java, jsonschema

I am attempting to generate Java classes from a third party JSON schema using [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo), so I need to go with the names of classes.  One of the classes is called `System`.  As a result, for all classes other than that class, there is an error in the `toString()` method:

```
package com.example;

// within a class

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(Status.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
    ...
}
```

The issue is in the call to `System.identityHashCode()`, because the System class is resolved to be the class in the same package, not the `java.lang.System` class.  The call within the `System` class that's generated looks like this:

```
sb.append(System.class.getName()).append('@').append(Integer.toHexString(java.lang.System.identityHashCode(this))).append('[');
```

The JSON can be any JSON at all, i.e. even `{ "type": "object" }` for 2 classes, one called `System` and another called `Foo` will cause the error.  I am generating the code using the Java API, like this:

```
String packageName = "com.example";
JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
    @Override
    public boolean isGenerateBuilders() { // set config option by overriding method
        return true;
    }
};
SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new Jackson2Annotator(config), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());

mapper.generate(codeModel, #NAME_OF_CLASS#, packageName, SOME_URL);
codeModel.build(outputDir);
```

How can I generate the code such that the fully qualified `java.lang.System` class is used for all classes?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can update your sample JSON in question.

Comment: Added - the error happens for all JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was an issue with Intellij.  The generated classes were correct, I just copied them from a generated directory to a source directory, and Intellij thought it would be helpful and simplify the class as part of the copy.  As a result, this actually broke the generated classes.